How to replace/expand environmental variables in AppSettings.json/DbContext for resolving local paths to SQLite while allowing overwrites of the path?
I have basically followed two docs. This simple here just explains a very simple EF SqLite configuration where DbContext just hardcodes .UseSqlite with a local path to "local application data". Here the relevant snippet:
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public string DbPath { get; }

    public BloggingContext()
    {
        var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "blogging.db");
    }

    // The following configures EF to create a Sqlite database file in the
    // special "local" folder for your platform.
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
}

On Windows, this obviously is %LocalAppData%. So far, so okay.
However, obviously I want to make this configurable and this is also suggested everywhere.
Microsoft docs itself suggest it here or e.g. here for Razor pages.
It basically boils down to:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingContext")));

Also, I need to add a constructor that can be passed in with the options, otherwise it won't work:
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

Now, however, when I do this, I need to decide whether to remove the OnConfiguring method above to let the options being read from appsettings.json. Or I want to hardcode the options, but then the JSON settings are ignored.
However, I just want it to keep that path (by default), but make it configurable. That's my use case here.
Now, if the path %LocalAppData%/blogging.db would be a local/usual path, that would not be an issue. I could just set that as the default value in the appsettings.json.
However, it is an issue, because apparently .NET (Core) does not interpret/expand environmental variables (like %LocalAppData%) in the settings. As such, you would need to use the full absolute path, which makes it not work in a cross-platform way.
Searching for solving this online is a pain, because it will always suggest you how to use environmental variables to overwrite the appsettings.json, which is not what I want. However, I've found this question, which likely would work.
That said, this would be a huge workaround and really sounds like a bit too much for such a simple (and IMHO common?) use case.
The minimum, simpler solution, here would be to fall back to the hardcoded fallback mentioned above.
How can I do a simple task like loading the settings aka connection string from the AppSettings.json while falling back/allowing a hardcoded one? (which contains environmental variables)

Ah, well the easiest obvious solution is probably just to replace/expand the environment variable using Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables for that specific variable:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite(
            Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingContext")!)
        );
    }
);

Then you can obviously define it like that in your appsettings.json:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingContext": "Data Source=%LocalAppData%\\blogging.db"
  }

